# MongoDB C#Driver 2.0: Why can't I use a boolean method in Query?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am using the C# MongoDB driver version 2.1.0, and have the following issue: I have a static class that handles the db connection etc., where I expose properties as follows,

```
public static class StaticMongo {

    private readonly static MongoClient Client;
    private readonly static IMongoDatabase Database;

    public static IMongoQueryable<Game> GetGames { 
        get {
            return Database.GetCollection<Game>("Games").AsQueryable();
        } 
    }
    // ...
}
```

Each `Game` has a list of `Player` which contains a `Name` property (and more, ofc). When accessing data, e.g., get all `Player` instances called `_name` from `Games` the following works:

```
var a = StaticMongo.GetHands.
    Where(n => (int)n.GameType == i).
    //Where(n => GamePassesFilter(n, true)).
    SelectMany(n => n.Players).
    Where(n => n.Name == _name).ToList();
```

But if I additionally want to filter them (i.e., if I include the commented line), like this one,

```
private bool GamePassesFilter(Game _game, bool _manyAllowed) {
    var _playersInGame = _game.Players.Count();
    if (_manyAllowed && (_playersInGame == 5 ||_playersInGame == 6)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

I get an exception. Why? And how should this be handled corretly?

> In System.ArgumentException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "MongoDB.Driver.dll" aufgetreten, doch wurde diese im Benutzercode
>   nicht verarbeitet.
>
> Zusätzliche Informationen: Unsupported filter:
>   value(MGM8.ViewModels.PlayersViewModel).GamePassesFilter([document]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User functions in `IMongoQueryable.Where` methods cannot be translated to `FilterDefinition` in the driver's [`PredicateTranslator`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/Translators/PredicateTranslator.cs#L725).

If you are allowed to do this, you can use `GamePassesFilter` by calling `AsEnumerable()` before that:

```
StaticMongo.GetHands.AsEnumerable().Where(n => GamePassesFilter(n, true))...
```

Or, you can just write all the conditions in the query.

```
StaticMongo.GetHands.Where(n => n.Players.Count() == 5 || n.Players.Count() == 6 && _manyAllowed)...
```

Comment: Thanks, will try both I guess. The latter works in this case, but when the filters get more complicated, it'd be nice to refactor them into a method, especially since they are used in several queries  ...